# How to open an IIS website without specifying port number in the url

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, web, port-number

I have a website hosted on IIS server and it is listening on port 81. So, to open the website I need to use the url http://server:81/site_name. I want to be able to open the website without having to specify the port number i.e. http://server/site_name.

Comment: Set the port number to 80.

Comment: @LexLi I cannot use port 80 as it is used by another application

Comment: learn how to use host names. You can host multiple sites at 80.